# When is a function of three variables a function of a function of three variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f: D \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$, $g: D \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$. If there is a function $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = h(g(x))$ then $$   \nabla f(x) \times \nabla g(x) = 0, \qquad \forall x \in D $$ since $\nabla f = h'(g(x)) \nabla g$. Is the converse true? Namely, if 
$$ \nabla f(x) \times \nabla g(x) = 0, \qquad \forall x \in D$$ then is it true that there exists a function $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = h(g(x))$. If not, which additional conditions should be added to make it work. I think, $\nabla f(x) \ne 0$,  and $\nabla g(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in D$ should be added. Everything can be assumed to be as smooth as needed.

Comment: You are implicitly assuming that $f,g,h$ are differentiable here. If you drop this assumption, then $f(x)=h(g(x))$ for some $h$ iff, for any $x_1,x_2$, if $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$, then $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

Comment: Yes. Everything can be assumed to be as smooth as needed.